# How to stop header redirects on PHP notice errors?

Tags: php, redirect, header

How to stop the code from completing the redirect if a **PHP notice error** happens? When working on Ubuntu local LAMP for development some notice errors are missed! But those same errors on the live server stops the header redirects.

What I am trying to do is catch those errors on the the local development server before they show up on the live server. How can I accomplish this? - headers already sent))?

Notice Errors:

[image]

Comment: What are those *some notice error*?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan I added a screenshot

Comment: So show admin/Users.php files 1896 line. What framework are you using? What is your php.ini settings `error_reporting`, `display_errors`. These should be as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display/21429652#21429652)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan all errors show on the developer's PC, the problem is that unlike the Centos server to see these errors you need to stop the redirect function (comment it) after the notice error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your `php.ini` in your Ubuntu server, and restart the web service:

```
output_buffering = 4096
```

to

```
output_buffering = Off
```

Alternatively, call `ob_end_flush()` before doing anything else in your Ubuntu server, but that makes the code inconsistent with the other environment.